# How to find the probability and generating function for this problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

We toss a coin $k$ times which is having probability $p$ of landing on heads and a probability $q = 1−p$ of landing on tails. The probability of getting exactly $n$ heads is denoted by $a_n$ . What is $a_n$ and the generating function of the sequence $(a_n)$?

What I thought of:

- Number of ways to get $n$ heads exactly is <sup>k</sup>C<sub>n</sub>
- Probability of getting 1 head is $p$
- Probability of getting n heads is $p^n$
- $a_n$ = <sup>k</sup>C<sub>n</sub>$p^n$

But the answer is : <sup>k</sup>C<sub>n</sub>.$p^n.q^{(k-n)}$.

So **I** don't think **I** am doing it right.

Comment: The given solution is not the generating function of $a_n$ It is the pmf of the binomial distribution with $k$ tosses and $n$ successes. You have to regard the probability of $k-n$ tails.

Comment: The probability on exactly one head by 2 tosses is $2pq$. This because we have the possible outcomes HT and TH.  This might make you understand the appearance of $q$.

Comment: @callculus42 yeah actually i did not mention generating function in the answer cuz i thought if i understood the probability part i will get the latter. But the generating function given used that probability you are saying as pmf. So can we use pmf to generate generating function as we use probability to generate generating function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pmf is $\binom{k}{n}\cdot p^n\cdot q^{k-n}, \ \forall n\in \{0,1,...,k\}$. It follows that the generating function is

$$\sum_{n=0}^k e^{nt}\cdot \binom{k}{n}\cdot p^n\cdot q^{k-n}=\sum_{n=0}^k\binom{k}{n}\cdot \left(pe^{t}\right)^n\cdot q^{k-n}$$

Now use the binominal theorem.